# Push object into a two level array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.
I have also read mongodb documentation on update but what i was looking for was not there.
So i have this `Schema` named `subSchoolSchema` for my model `subschool`

```
var subSchoolSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    schoolid: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    departments: [{
        name: String,
        hod: String,
        duration: Number,
        classes: [{
            title: String,
            students: [{
                schId: String,
                firstname: String,
                lastname: String,
                othername: String,
                password: String,
                email: String,
                group: String,
                issues: Array,
                notes: String,
                chatId: String,
                fcm_token: String,
                state: Number,
                type: Number,
                suspended: Boolean,
                details: [{
                    key: String,
                    value: String
                }],
                courses: [{
                    title: String,
                    code: String,
                    credit: Number,
                    instructor: String,
                    instructorId: String,
                    score: Number
                }],
                img: {
                    type: String,
                    default: "svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
})
```

I want to push an object into `departments.classes.students` using this code

```
var stud = { schId: id, firstname: fname, lastname: lname, othername: othername, email: email, group: grp, password: password, state: 2, type: 0, img: dp, details: details }
subschool.update({ username: request.session.code, "departments.classes._id": studentClass }, {
    "$push": {
        "departments.classes.students" : stud
            }
    }, function (er, result) {
        if(er){
            console.log(er)
        } else {
            res.end('{"status" : 0,"success":1}')
        }
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
{ CastError: Cast to [number] failed for value "[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password"
:"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,"img":"svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]" at path "student
s"
    at MongooseError.CastError (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:26:11)
    at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:184:15)
    at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:195:15)
    at castUpdateVal (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:266:22)
    at walkUpdatePath (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:143:22)
    at castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:71:18)
    at Query._castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2902:10)
    at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2752:23)
    at Query.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2547:10)
    at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2448:16)
    at Function.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2364:10)
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\routes\students\studentapi.js:33:15
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16)
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
  message: 'Cast to [number] failed for value "[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password":
"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,"img":"svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]" at path "students
"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password":"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,
"img":"svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]"',
  kind: '[number]',
  value: '[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password":"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,"img":"
svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]',
  path: 'students',
  reason:
   { CastError: Cast to number failed for value "{ schId: 'nj122',
     firstname: 'djnk',
     lastname: 'jjkn',
     othername: 'kn',
     email: 'inei@iiu.edn',
     group: 'B',
     password: '7f6f5e9d',
     state: 2,
     type: 0,
     img: 'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg',
     details:
      [ { key: 'Gender', value: 'Male' },
        { key: 'Blood Type', value: 'V0' } ] }" at path "students"
       at MongooseError.CastError (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:26:11)
       at SchemaNumber.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\number.js:231:9)
       at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:180:34)
       at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:195:15)
       at castUpdateVal (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:266:22)
       at walkUpdatePath (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:143:22)
       at castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:71:18)
       at Query._castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2902:10)
       at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2752:23)
       at Query.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2547:10)
       at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2448:16)
       at Function.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2364:10)
       at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\routes\students\studentapi.js:33:15
       at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16)
       at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
       at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
     message: 'Cast to number failed for value "{ schId: \'nj122\',\n  firstname: \'djnk\',\n  lastname: \'jjkn\',\n  othername: \'kn\',\n  email: \'inei@iiu.edn\',\
n  group: \'B\',\n  password: \'7f6f5e9d\',\n  state: 2,\n  type: 0,\n  img: \'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg\',\n  details: \n   [ { key: \'Gender\', value: \'Male\'
},\n     { key: \'Blood Type\', value: \'V0\' } ] }" at path "students"',
     name: 'CastError',
     stringValue: '"{ schId: \'nj122\',\n  firstname: \'djnk\',\n  lastname: \'jjkn\',\n  othername: \'kn\',\n  email: \'inei@iiu.edn\',\n  group: \'B\',\n  password
: \'7f6f5e9d\',\n  state: 2,\n  type: 0,\n  img: \'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg\',\n  details: \n   [ { key: \'Gender\', value: \'Male\' },\n     { key: \'Blood Type
\', value: \'V0\' } ] }"',
     kind: 'number',
     value:
      { schId: 'nj122',
        firstname: 'djnk',
        lastname: 'jjkn',
        othername: 'kn',
        email: 'inei@iiu.edn',
        group: 'B',
        password: '7f6f5e9d',
        state: 2,
        type: 0,
        img: 'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg',
        details: [Object] },
     path: 'students',
     reason: undefined } }
{ username: 'AA',
  'departments.classes._id': '59669687abf46f170045cc6e' }
{ CastError: Cast to [number] failed for value "[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password"
:"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,"img":"svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]" at path "student
s"
    at MongooseError.CastError (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:26:11)
    at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:184:15)
    at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:195:15)
    at castUpdateVal (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:266:22)
    at walkUpdatePath (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:143:22)
    at castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:71:18)
    at Query._castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2902:10)
    at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2752:23)
    at Query.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2547:10)
    at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2448:16)
    at Function.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2364:10)
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\routes\students\studentapi.js:33:15
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16)
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
  message: 'Cast to [number] failed for value "[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password":
"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,"img":"svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]" at path "students
"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password":"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,
"img":"svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]"',
  kind: '[number]',
  value: '[{"schId":"nj122","firstname":"djnk","lastname":"jjkn","othername":"kn","email":"inei@iiu.edn","group":"B","password":"7f6f5e9d","state":2,"type":0,"img":"
svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg","details":[{"key":"Gender","value":"Male"},{"key":"Blood Type","value":"V0"}]}]',
  path: 'students',
  reason:
   { CastError: Cast to number failed for value "{ schId: 'nj122',
     firstname: 'djnk',
     lastname: 'jjkn',
     othername: 'kn',
     email: 'inei@iiu.edn',
     group: 'B',
     password: '7f6f5e9d',
     state: 2,
     type: 0,
     img: 'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg',
     details:
      [ { key: 'Gender', value: 'Male' },
        { key: 'Blood Type', value: 'V0' } ] }" at path "students"
       at MongooseError.CastError (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:26:11)
       at SchemaNumber.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\number.js:231:9)
       at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:180:34)
       at SchemaArray.cast (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:195:15)
       at castUpdateVal (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:266:22)
       at walkUpdatePath (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:143:22)
       at castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:71:18)
       at Query._castUpdate (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2902:10)
       at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2752:23)
       at Query.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2547:10)
       at _update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2448:16)
       at Function.update (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2364:10)
       at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\routes\students\studentapi.js:33:15
       at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16)
       at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
       at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\School Sync\ikey\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
     message: 'Cast to number failed for value "{ schId: \'nj122\',\n  firstname: \'djnk\',\n  lastname: \'jjkn\',\n  othername: \'kn\',\n  email: \'inei@iiu.edn\',\
n  group: \'B\',\n  password: \'7f6f5e9d\',\n  state: 2,\n  type: 0,\n  img: \'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg\',\n  details: \n   [ { key: \'Gender\', value: \'Male\'
},\n     { key: \'Blood Type\', value: \'V0\' } ] }" at path "students"',
     name: 'CastError',
     stringValue: '"{ schId: \'nj122\',\n  firstname: \'djnk\',\n  lastname: \'jjkn\',\n  othername: \'kn\',\n  email: \'inei@iiu.edn\',\n  group: \'B\',\n  password
: \'7f6f5e9d\',\n  state: 2,\n  type: 0,\n  img: \'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg\',\n  details: \n   [ { key: \'Gender\', value: \'Male\' },\n     { key: \'Blood Type
\', value: \'V0\' } ] }"',
     kind: 'number',
     value:
      { schId: 'nj122',
        firstname: 'djnk',
        lastname: 'jjkn',
        othername: 'kn',
        email: 'inei@iiu.edn',
        group: 'B',
        password: '7f6f5e9d',
        state: 2,
        type: 0,
        img: 'svg/icon_student_sync_dp.svg',
        details: [Object] },
     path: 'students',
     reason: undefined } }
```

I don't know what to do to avoid this error, it keeps showing cast error, but in the above schema i defined it as an `array`. I would be very happy if i can get a solution to this question. Thanks.

Comment: Make your life easier and "do not nest arrays". Just like everyone else who makes the same mistake your seem to think the "nested levels" allow you to "filter" properly for queries. They do not, and in fact make constructing effective queries and updates even worse. Instead make every "nesting" a "property" of a single flat array. These are then simple to update and query by singular positional matches. Don't try and force something that simply does not work how you think it does.

Comment: There are also more natural relational elements here rather than embedded. Much of this should indeed be in separate collections.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will use separate models